# How can you add json data to object?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, object

So i have a array object like so

```
var data = [
        {
            value: 300,
            label: "Red"
        },
        {
            value: 50,
            label: "Green"
        },
        {
            value: 100,
            label: "Yellow"
        }
    ]
```

And then i have a ajax request which gets the json data like so

```
$.getJSON('ajax/bestseller_chart.php', {id:$('#bestsellersChart').data('storeid')}, function(result){
        $.each(result, function(i, field){
            console.log(field['item']);
            console.log(field['num_sold']);
        });
});
```

So i am trying to append the field['item'] to label and 'num_sold' to value

This is what iv tried but it didnt work

```
data.label = field['item'];
data.value = field['num_sold'];
```

Comment: I don't see `item` or `num_sold` in your object? So where are they coming from?

Comment: they are coming from the php data. And item will be label and num_sold is value

Comment: Have you tried Jquery.parseJson which can convert you json to js object?

Comment: Your object `data` is an array. You need to index it to set the properties of the items *in that array*. Something like: `data[0].label = field['item'];`. But it's not clear how you expect to match objects in your json to existing objects in your object.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to populate an array from your JSON, it's not clear what you want or expect to do with the existing values. If the idea is to replace the existing array, then you can just do that like so:

```
var data = [];
$.getJSON('ajax/bestseller_chart.php', {id:$('#bestsellersChart').data('storeid')}, function(result){
        $.each(result, function(i, field){
            data.push({ 
                label:field['item'], 
                value:field['num_sold'] 
            });
        });
});
```